# Disabling AD account from a list one account per day

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to disable the AD account based on the input.TXT file one AD account per day, followed by an email when successful.

Input.TXT content:

```
User1.Name
Person1.Name
Person2.name
user2.Name
...
UserX.name
PersonX.Name
```

If the scheduled task is restarted, the script should ideally continue to the next active AD account in the list.

This script will be run using the Scheduled task at 12:01 AM every midnight.

So far, here's what I've produced:

```
$users = Get-Content "C:\userlist.txt"
$emailFrom = "your@email.com"
$emailTo = "recipient@email.com"
$smtpServer = "smtp.yourserver.com"

foreach ($user in $users) {
    try {
        Disable-ADAccount $user
        Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject "User Account Disabled" -Body "$user's account has been disabled." -SmtpServer $smtpServer
    } catch {
        Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject "Error Disabling User Account" -Body "An error occurred while disabling $user's account: $_" -SmtpServer $smtpServer
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 86400
}
```

Comment: I think just removing the processed line and saving the file will be much easier than a loop ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd have thought so. But not sure how to do the File operations in this case. I assume once the successful AD account is disabled, then the removal process can start for the next day.

Comment: How about splitting the input into multiple files, like one case per file. When script's being run, pick one file for processing and delete (or archive) it after you are done. Or load up the data in a database?

Comment: Thank you Theo & Santiago, I will try the script with the Task scheduler to see if it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally let the task finish daily removing one user at a time from the file. A Queue makes sense to me but could be also done with a List.

```bash
try {
    [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[string]] $users = Get-Content 'C:\userlist.txt'

    # is there something to process in the file?
    if(-not $users.Count) {
        # if not, the just exit this task
        return
    }
    # get the first user in queue
    $first = $users.Dequeue()

    $sendMailMessageSplat = @{
        From       = 'your@email.com'
        To         = 'recipient@email.com'
        Subject    = 'User Account Disabled'
        Body       = "$first's account has been disabled."
        SmtpServer = 'smtp.yourserver.com'
    }

    $user = Get-ADUser $first
    # if the user is enabled
    if($user.Enabled) {
        # disable and send email
        $user | Disable-ADAccount
        Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
    }
    # if they were already disabled, nothing to do
    # save the file
    Set-Content 'C:\userlist.txt' -Value $users.ToArray()
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
    # if this user doesn't exist, then just save the file.
    # could send email here too if needed
    Set-Content 'C:\userlist.txt' -Value $users.ToArray()
}
catch {
    # if something failed send the email. file is not saved in this case
    # as this use will need to be re-processed
    $sendMailMessageSplat['Subject'] = 'Error Disabling User Account'
    $sendMailMessageSplat['Body'] = "An error occurred while disabling $first's account: $_"
    Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by reading the file (skipping empty lines), taking the top line as the user to disable and then save the rest of the lines back to the file to process the next day.

```
$inputFile = 'C:\userlist.txt'
# read the file, skipping empty or whitespace-only lines
$content = Get-Content -Path $inputFile | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

# create a splatting Hashtable
$mailParams = @{
    From       = 'your@email.com'
    To         = 'recipient@email.com'
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.yourserver.com'
}

# are there any lines left?
if (@($content).Count -eq 0) {
    $mailParams['Subject'] = "File '$inputFile' is empty"
    $mailParams['Body']    = "No users to disable in file '$inputFile'"
}
else {
    # get the first line
    $user = $content[0]
    # and save all further lines back to the file to process the next day
    $content | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $inputFile -Force

    try {
        Disable-ADAccount -Identity $user -ErrorAction Stop
        $mailParams['Subject'] = 'User Account Disabled'
        $mailParams['Body']    = "$user's account has been disabled."
    }
    catch {
        $mailParams['Subject'] = 'Error Disabling User Account'
        $mailParams['Body']    = "An error occurred while disabling $user's account: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
# send out the email
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Comment: Many thanks to you @theo, for your assistance with this question, your solution is also working, but for some reason, I cannot accept both as answers.